# Getting the null pointer exception in the getActionBar method

Tags: android, android-activity

I have use menu items on the action bar. but while getting it in the on create method it giving me the null pointer exception. Please help

Thanks

here is the oncreate method code

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


     final ActionBar localActionBar=getActionBar();
     localActionBar.setNavigationMode(2);
     this.mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
     this.mViewPager = ((ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager));
     this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
        {
             public void onPageSelected(int paramAnonymousInt)
             {
               localActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(paramAnonymousInt);
             }
           });
        for (int i = 0; i < this.mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) 
        {
            localActionBar.addTab(localActionBar.newTab().setText(this.mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }

}
```

and the Log cat errors

```
log01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chronos.cricketgraph/com.chronos.cricketgraph.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at com.chronos.cricketgraph.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:48)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
01-15 13:37:09.092: E/AndroidRuntime(15604):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
'
```

Comment: does your activity has an ActionBar? are you using some other theme?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Theme.AppCompat`, then extend `ActionBarActivity`. Also use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. You might also need to enable title (but I am not sure if thats true for all android versions) - so `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` should be removed - do you have in your theme:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

by any chance.

Comment: Does replacing `getActionBar()` with `getSupportActionBar()` fixes your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use a theme for your application that provides the `AcionBar`, maybe you can include the `appcompact` support library.

You can give a look at [this post](http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html):

Answer (score 1):

Did you extend ActionBarActivity?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show(); 
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ...
}
```

Comment: my activity extends ActionBar.TabListener... But even I tried ActionBarActivity...but it is giving me error

Comment: It should extend ActionBarActivity implement ActionBar.TabListener

Comment: It would be helpful to know what line is causing the crash?

Comment: Line ->  localActionBar.setNavigationMode(2);

Comment: I changed my answer above to extend FragmentActivity

Comment: Also my themes parent had to be <style name="Theme.Apptheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 0):

Depends of your version (in Manifest) you need to use `getSupportActionBar();` or `getActionBar();`. Also are you sure what your `homeActivy` are extending from an `Activity.class` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the getSupportedActionBar-Method. I think you use another version of android